# laracasts doesn't work (ReferenceError: foo is not defined)

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel-6

I'm using laravel6 and laracasts https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer.

My controller looks like this.

```
public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::where('user_id', '<>', \Auth::id())->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(3);
        \JavaScript::put([
            'foo' => 'bar',
        ]);
        return view('posts/index', ['posts' => $posts]);
    }
```

And here is my `index.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{ config('app.name')}}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/css/main.css') }}">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <a class="brand" href="/">{{ config('app.name') }}</a>
            @include('commons/nav')
        </div>
    </header>

    <main>
        <script>
            console.log(foo);
        </script>
        
        <div class="container2">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run, I got `Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined` on browser console.
I think I literally copy and paste the sample code on https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer

Can anybody tell me what's wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `@include ('footer')` call in the `index.blade.php` file just above the bottom of the body.

https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer

Comment: Thanks! However, that doesn't fix. I changed `config/javascript.php` like this ```'bind_js_vars_to_this_view' => ['posts/index']``` then, if fixed.